# Sum columns every two rows in R

Tags: r, sum, row

I have a dataframe with 304 rows and 32 variables. I would like to sum the values from column A and column B for every 2 rows (i.e., row1+row2, row3+row4, row5+row6, and so on). In the column OUTPUT you can see what I would like to obtain.

```
 A      B   OUTPUT  
 0      23  0       #row1
 1000   0   1023    #row2
 0      12  0       #row3
 914    0   926     #row4
 0      25  0       #row5
 502    0   527     #row6
 0      16  0       #row7
 644    0   660     #row8
 0      23  0       #row9
 776    0   799     #row10
 0      19  0       #row11
 860    0   879     #row12
 0      25  0       #row13
 992    0   1017    #row14
 0      15  0       #row15
 1153   0   1168    #row16
 0      17  0       #row17
 615    0   632     #row18
 0      32  0       #row19
 588    0   620     #row20
 0      36  0       #row21
 814    0   850     #row22
 0      29  0       #row23
 1103   0   1132    #row24
 0      16  0       #row25
 690    0   706     #row26
 0      22  0       #row27
 456    0   478     #row28
 0      16  0       #row29
 1292   0   1308    #row30
```

I have tried using:

```
 library(RcppRoll)
 df1$OUTPUT <- with(df1, round(roll_sumr((df1$A + df1$B), n = 2, by=2,  fill = 0)))
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your approach works for me. What error are you getting?

Comment: @HFBrowning I obtain: `0 1023  479  926  289  527  276  660  364  799  542  879  539 1017  602 1168  403  632  535  620  424  850  585 1132  499  706  286  478  800 1308`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the many possible solutions:

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(0L, 1000L, 0L, 914L, 0L, 502L, 0L, 644L, 
0L, 776L, 0L, 860L, 0L, 992L, 0L, 1153L, 0L, 615L, 0L, 588L, 
0L, 814L, 0L, 1103L, 0L, 690L, 0L, 456L, 0L, 1292L), B = c(23L, 
0L, 12L, 0L, 25L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 23L, 0L, 19L, 0L, 25L, 0L, 15L, 
0L, 17L, 0L, 32L, 0L, 36L, 0L, 29L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 22L, 0L, 16L, 
0L), OUTPUT = c(0L, 1023L, 0L, 926L, 0L, 527L, 0L, 660L, 0L, 
799L, 0L, 879L, 0L, 1017L, 0L, 1168L, 0L, 632L, 0L, 620L, 0L, 
850L, 0L, 1132L, 0L, 706L, 0L, 478L, 0L, 1308L)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "OUTPUT"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))

df1$OUTPUT <- c(0, sapply(2:nrow(df1), function(k) df1$A[k]+df1$B[k-1]))

head(df1)
#      A  B OUTPUT
# 1    0 23      0
# 2 1000  0   1023
# 3    0 12      0
# 4  914  0    926
# 5    0 25      0
# 6  502  0    527
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R method using `tapply` and the modulus operator, `%%`.

```
dat$temp <- unlist(tapply(rowSums(dat), list(cumsum(seq_len(nrow(dat)) %% 2)),
                          FUN=function(x) c(0, sum(x))))
```

Here, the row sums are calculated and fed to the first argument of `tapply`. The second argument, which performs the grouping is calculated as the cumulative sum of rows that are modulus 2. The function returns a 0 concatenated with the sum of the each group. Here, `tapply` returns a list which is turned into a numeric vector with `unlist`.

The first six rows of the result are

```
head(dat)
     A  B temp
1    0 23    0
2 1000  0 1023
3    0 12    0
4  914  0  926
5    0 25    0
6  502  0  527
```

Note that `rowSums(dat)` will try to perform a row-wise summation of your entire data.frame. If your data.frame has more than 2 columns and you want to restrict the operation to two columns in particular, you need to subset this argument. According to the code in the OP, with a data.frame named df1, you could replace this with `rowSums(df1[c("A", "B")])` to get the desired result.

**data**

```
    dat <-
    structure(list(A = c(0L, 1000L, 0L, 914L, 0L, 502L, 0L, 644L, 
    0L, 776L, 0L, 860L, 0L, 992L, 0L, 1153L, 0L, 615L, 0L, 588L, 
    0L, 814L, 0L, 1103L, 0L, 690L, 0L, 456L, 0L, 1292L), B = c(23L, 
    0L, 12L, 0L, 25L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 23L, 0L, 19L, 0L, 25L, 0L, 15L, 
    0L, 17L, 0L, 32L, 0L, 36L, 0L, 29L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 22L, 0L, 16L, 
    0L)), .Names = c("A", "B"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It gives me this error: `Error in rowSums(dat) : 'x' must be numeric`

Comment: That means that at least one of your columns is not numeric and so calculating the sum does not make sense. It works on the example you provided which read in and provided at the end of my answer (dropping the third column of expected output).

Comment: yes, one of the two columns is numeric, the other one integer.

Comment: An integer is numeric. you can test this with `is.numeric(1L)` or `is.numeric(as.integer(1))`. The column most likely either a character vector or factor. Use `str(my_df)` to check the types of variables you are using. If your data.frame has more than 2 columns, you will need to subset to the columns on which you want to perform the calculation. Form the code at the bottom of your post, you want `colSums(df[c("A", "B")]`.